# Multiselect in a dropdown list in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, dropdown, bootstrap-multiselect

I am trying to be able to multi select different values from a dropdown I created. So the following code is actually showing the names of the people but I would like to be able to select more than one.

```js
<Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect4">
    <Form.Label> Names </Form.Label>
    <Form.Control as="select" value={this.state.selectedNames} 
                  onChange={this.updateTable}>
        {this.state.names.map((name) => <option key={name.value} value={name.value}> {name.display } </option>)}
    </Form.Control>
</Form.Group>
```

Comment: Are you using react-bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

It is similar to setting a single value but instead, the value is an array instead of a string or a number.

First, you have to change what the value and onChange function are doing. For the value, set the default state as an array. For the `onChange`, we are going to set it where whenever the item is checked, it sets a new state so like this:

**javascript**

```
state = {
 selectedNames:[]
}

onChange = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  this.setState(prevState => ({selectedNames: [...prevState.selectedNames, e.target.value]})
}
```

Hopefully, this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The event needs to be added to individual option, multi select takes quite a bit of lines to implement. Here's some snippet just for the sections you might care. I'm not using any third party controls as you can see.

```
      <div className="_action">
        <span
          role="button"
          aria-pressed="false"
          tabIndex={0}
          onClick={() => { onClear() }}
        >
          Clear Selection
        </span>
      </div>
      {options.map(option => (
        <div
          role="presentation"
          className="_item"
          key={option.value}
          onClick={() => { onSelect(option.value) }}
        >
          <Checkbox value={isChecked(option, value)} />
          <span className="_label">{option.label}</span>
        </div>
      ))}
```

The `onSelect` and `onClear` might be provided from parent/self component,

```
  const onSelect = useCallback(v => {
    const e = {
      target: {
        name,
        value: toggleValueInOptions(value, v, options)
      }
    }
    onChange(e)
  }, [name, value, options, onChange])

  const onClear = useCallback(() => {
    const e = { target: { name, value: [] } }
    onChange(e)
  }, [name, onChange])
```

and a utility function `toggleValueiInOptions`

```
const toggleValueInOptions = (value, key, options) => {
  if (!value) return []

  const values = value.slice()
  const index = values.indexOf(key)
  if (index >= 0) {
    values.splice(index, 1)
  } else {
    values.push(key)
  }

  if (!options) return values

  return options.reduce((acc, option) => {
    if (values.includes(option.value)) {
      acc.push(option.value)
    }
    return acc
  }, [])
}

export default toggleValueInOptions
```

## ==============

For your reference, this is the complete code for the parent `MultiSelect`.

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useRef } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { useClickOutside } from '../../utils'
import InputBase from '../InputBase'
import Pills from './Pills'
import MultiSelection from './MultiSelection'
import MultiSelectStyle from './MultiSelectStyle'
import SelectIcon from './SelectIcon'
import { optionsType, valuesType } from './optionsType'
import toggleValueInOptions from './toggleValueInOptions'
import valueToItems from './valueToItems'
import SelectionSummary from './SelectionSummary'

/**
 * @memberof MultiSelect
 * @param {Object} _                Props
 * @param {elementType} _.Style       Style component
 * @param {string} _.name             Input name
 * @param {valueType[]} _.value         Input value of array
 * @param {func} _.onChange           Value change event
 * @param {optionsType[]} _.options     Options array
 * @param {elementType} _.Selection=MultiSelection    Component for dropdown selection
 * @param {bool} _.disabled=false     Input disabled flag
 * @param {bool} _.width=auto         Input width
 * @param {string} _.placeholder      Input placeholder
 * @param {elementType} _.DropdownIcon=DropdownIcon   Compoent for dropdown icon component
 * @param {number} _.pillVisibleMax   Max pill displayed
 * @param {elementType} _.Summary=SelectionSummary    Component for dropdown summary
 */
const MultiSelect = ({
  Style, name, value, options, onChange,
  Selection, disabled, width, placeholder,
  DropdownIcon, pillVisibleMax, Summary,
  ...props
}) => {
  const [focus, setFocus] = useState(false)

  const onExpand = useCallback(() => {
    if (!disabled) setFocus(true)
  }, [disabled])
  const onCollapse = useCallback(() => { setFocus(false) }, [])
  const ref = useRef()
  useClickOutside({ ref, handler: () => { onCollapse() } })

  const onSelect = useCallback(v => {
    const e = {
      target: {
        name,
        value: toggleValueInOptions(value, v, options)
      }
    }
    onChange(e)
  }, [name, value, options, onChange])

  const onClear = useCallback(() => {
    const e = { target: { name, value: [] } }
    onChange(e)
  }, [name, onChange])

  const after = <DropdownIcon focus={focus} onExpand={onExpand} onCollapse={onCollapse} />

  const phText = value.length ? '' : placeholder
  const vText = (value.length > pillVisibleMax) ? `${value.length} Selected` : ''

  return (
    <Style ref={ref}>
      <InputBase
        value={vText}
        placeholder={phText}
        disabled={disabled}
        readOnly
        after={after}
        onFocus={onExpand}
        width={width}
        {...props}
      />
      {!vText && (
        <Pills
          items={valueToItems(value, options)}
          onSelect={onSelect}
          disabled={disabled}
        />
      )}
      {focus && (
        <Selection
          value={value}
          options={options}
          onSelect={onSelect}
          onClear={onClear}
          Summary={Summary}
        />
      )}
    </Style>
  )
}

MultiSelect.propTypes = {
  Style: PropTypes.elementType,
  name: PropTypes.string,
  value: valuesType,
  options: optionsType,
  onChange: PropTypes.func,
  Selection: PropTypes.elementType,
  disabled: PropTypes.bool,
  width: PropTypes.string,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  DropdownIcon: PropTypes.elementType,
  pillVisibleMax: PropTypes.number,
  Summary: PropTypes.elementType
}

MultiSelect.defaultProps = {
  Style: MultiSelectStyle,
  name: '',
  value: [],
  options: [],
  onChange: () => { },
  Selection: MultiSelection,
  disabled: false,
  width: '',
  placeholder: '',
  DropdownIcon: SelectIcon,
  pillVisibleMax: 99,
  Summary: SelectionSummary
}

export default MultiSelect
```

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming you are using `react-bootstrap`)

#### Answer

You will need to pass another prop to `Form.Control` to specify that you would like your select to allow multiple selections. You can do this either as `multiple={true}`, or as the shorthand `multiple` (both are equivalent).

[This example](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-controls) in their docs uses a multiselect, that might be helpful.

I put together this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-snowflake-sscx2?file=/src/App.js:252-299) which might illustrate how to use it.

#### What's tricky

Handling state with react can be hard. Forms are notoriously challenging because they involve a lot of internal state.

#### Other things to try

- Use react hooks to manage state instead of a class component. This can make it easier to work with state, in my opinion

#### Bug in my example

- When there is only one selection and you try to deselect it, the `onChange` event is not trigged. I'm not sure why that's happening here